# Setting the value in a for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a for loop that i need to increase the value of on each iteration, and a few examples of what I have tried so far.  I need to increase the value of tp on each loop through:

```
  for (var t = 9; t < 20; t++) {
    //Tried the below:
    var timePeriod = report_data[i] + '.tp' + t.toString();
    venues[i].scan_times[t] = timePeriod;

    //and:
    venues[i].scan_times[t] = report_data[i].tp + t;
  }
```

The manual way of doing it, which I am trying to use the for loop to accomplish:

```
venues[i].scan_times['9'] = report_data[i].tp9;
venues[i].scan_times['10'] = report_data[i].tp10;
....
venues[i].scan_times['19'] = report_data[i].tp19;
venues[i].scan_times['20'] = report_data[i].tp20;
```

Comment: So... Is `.scan_times` an array or an object?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can always access attributes in two ways: with bracket notation and dot notation

```
var myObj = {};

// those 2 lines are equivalent
myObj.a = 1;
myObj['a'] = 1
```

If you want to dynamically access some attributes you can use whatever you want inside the brackets.

```
// those 2 lines are equivalent
myObj['a' + 4] = 1;
myObj.a4 = 1;
```

In your case you can write

```
for (var t = 9; t < 20; t++) {
    venues[i].scan_times[t] = report_data[i]['tp' + t];
}
```